# Assertion failed Invalid spriteFrameName

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am building a game using `Cocos2dx`. I have a sprite sheet and animation plist that specifies where all the images are.

For some reason when loading my game I get the following error:

```
(char [256]) msg = "Invalid spriteFrameName: PlayButton.png"
```

It is coming from line 159 of `CCSprite.cpp`:

```
CCSprite* CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(const char *pszSpriteFrameName)
{
    CCSpriteFrame *pFrame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(pszSpriteFrameName);

#if COCOS2D_DEBUG > 0
    char msg[256] = {0};
    sprintf(msg, "Invalid spriteFrameName: %s", pszSpriteFrameName);
    CCAssert(pFrame != NULL, msg);
#endif

    return createWithSpriteFrame(pFrame);
}
```

I checked in my .plist and I do have an entry for PlayButton.png, so I have no idea why it says it is invalid.

That method is being called from the `MainMenu::init()` method:

```
fileName = (CCString*)sc->imageDict->objectForKey("GUI_StartButton-image");
CCSprite *startGameSprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName( fileName->m_sString.c_str() ); <--- CRASHING HERE
```

**What could be causing this?**

Comment: Provided information is not enough. At least, is there any other resource which is loaded successfully?

Comment: make sure you have added all images to Resources folder in xcode.

Comment: Do you see an "cocos2d: SpriteFrameCache: Frame 'PlayButton.png' not found" message in your log? Do you have a line of code where you load your sprites sheet? Something like this : 'CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("spritessheet.plist", "spritesheet.png");'

Comment: @VikasPatidar Yes they have been added there.

Comment: @SalvatoreAvanzo Ah that was it! I checked and for some reason one of my .plist files was not being loaded. Added and the error is gone. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can see the following message in your log console

```
cocos2d: SpriteFrameCache: Frame 'PlayButton.png' not found
```

and if that's true then you have to load your spritessheet :

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("spritess‌​heet.plist", "spritesheet.png");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Looks like somehow my last spritesheet was not being loaded!